# Django Error - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'strTypeError at

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, csv, operands

I received this error an i don't know why it happend.
*TypeError at /admin/ofac_sdn/ofac_sdn/
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'strTypeError.*

I have uploaded a csv directly to my models. 
These are the fields i used from the csv.

```
36,AEROCARIBBEAN AIRLINES,null ,CUBA,null,null,null,0,0,null,null,null
173,"ANGLO-CARIBBEAN CO., LTD.",null,CUBA,null,null,null,0,0,null,null,null
306,BANCO NACIONAL DE CUBA,null,CUBA,null,null,null,0,0,null,null,a.k.a. 'BNC'.
```

This is how my admin looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Sdn
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Add
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Alt
# Register your models here.    
admin.site.register(Ofac_Sdn)    
admin.site.register(Ofac_Add)
admin.site.register(Ofac_Alt)
```

These are my models:

```
class Ofac_Sdn(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    b_i = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    programe= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    more_info = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_call_sign = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_type= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_dwt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tonnage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    vessel_flag = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_owner= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    dob_aka= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
```

These are my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^ofac/', include('ofac_sdn.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

And this is what i have in my views. There is no view created, but i should see the inputs that I have in this ofac_sdn table/model.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1> Hi Cohen</h1>")
```

The thing is that i can see the records in my DB from an app, but they are not displayed in the admin. Thank you in advance!

Below is the full error:

```
TypeError at /admin/ofac_sdn/ofac_sdn/
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ofac_sdn/ofac_sdn/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
Exception Location: /Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/models.py in __str__, line 34
Python Executable:  /Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project',
 '/Users/cohen/anaconda/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/cohen/anaconda/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/cohen/anaconda/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 5 Sep 2017 08:42:29 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template /Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html, error at line 75
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
65            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
66          {% endfor %}</ul>
67          {% endif %}
68      {% endblock messages %}
69  
70      <!-- Content -->
71      <div id="content" class="{% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}">
72          {% block pretitle %}{% endblock %}
73          {% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
74          {% block content %}
75          {% block object-tools %}{% endblock %}
76          {{ content }}
77          {% endblock %}
78          {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
79          <br class="clear" />
80      </div>
81      <!-- END Content -->
82  
83      {% block footer %}<div id="footer"></div>{% endblock %}
84  </div>
85  <!-- END Container -->
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py in get_field
            return self.fields_map[field_name] ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
field_name  
'__str__'
self    
<Options for Ofac_Sdn>
```

Comment: post the model code where you are uploading the csv

Comment: Hey John, can you add the files names too? And is this the entire code?

Comment: And the full traceback.

Comment: hi guys, i've updated the post to include also the models! Thank you!

Comment: i cant see any filefield where you are uploading csv?

Comment: I have reedited the post. thank you!

Comment: can you post your full models?? or the line 34 of your models.py? else post the str function in line 33 of models.py

Comment: thank you! @Exprator you were right! on that line was the issue! I've learn something from you today! Thank you Sir!

Comment: I forgot to add `@property` in **models.py** when I got error: **unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'method'**. I think not many gets this error, just didn't realise I had to add `@property`. This was the first question that came up when searching for this error.

Answer (score 1):

you are somewhere adding a string and an int, probably a line of code like this:

```
return "foo" + n  # n being an int
```

You should replace this `+` by using a proper formatting, e.g.

```
return "foo %d" % n
```

or

```
return "foo {}".format(n)
```

If you really need to use `+`, you have to convert your `int` to a `str` first:

```
return "foo " + str(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! you were right! the issue was from my def. It had a `'+'` and somehow this cretaed the error. I could change the `+` sign into  a comma and now it works properly.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.number,  self.name,  self.programe
```

Comment: The method `__str__()` is supposed to return a string (`str`); you are currently returning a tuple which will probably lead to problems later (even if it doesn't right now).  You should return sth like `str((self.number, self.name, self.programe))` instead (the string representation of a tuple).

Comment: So you are saying to change it like this: **def __str__(self): str((self.number, self.name, self.programe))**? Thank you!

Comment: Well, `return` this value of course (you left that keyword out in your comment above).  And I propose to change your answer accordingly.  We can then remove all our comments below to reduce text load.